# Android app architecture design pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvvm, android-mvp

I'm looking to create a basic architecture of Android app boilerplate with (Login, SignUp, Other features that every app has). After lot of research I found that going with MVP is going to be best choice.

However I'm not getting the right way to implement MVP. I'm a beginner with this.

If someone can guide me with the right sources, it will be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the Architecture guides from Google:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

MVP sample from Google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/

Answer (score 0):

I did not seem to find and VERY SIMPLE "HELLO WORLD" example, so i created one on my own. clone this example and try using it as a template or reference to your project.

- the mvp-simple-hello-world branch is the most basic example of a toast pulled from a edit text.
- the master branch (still being worked on and added to) is a more extended example of small methods doing random things: toast from edit text, change background color, and API call to get weather information and display it on the screen.
  *for the Accuweather API call you need to register to https://developer.accuweather.com/ -->"My apps" tab --> make a new app. 
  then add the API_KEY to the "Constants" class.

Github repo: https://github.com/ayalus/MvpHelloWorld/tree/mvp-simple-hello-world